# Use namespaces with nested record types

Tags: avro

I ran into a problem with encapsulation in avro. I can’t figure out how to do this correctly and whether I should even use encapsulation

I have this avro

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "ChargesRequest",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "ExportConditions",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "ExportConditions",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "Conditions",
        "type" : [ "null", {
          "type" : "record",
          "name" : "Conditions",
          "fields" : [  {
            "name" : "TimeInterval",
            "type" : [ "null", {
              "type" : "record",
              "name" : "TimeInterval",
              "fields" : [ {
                "name" : "startDate",
                "type" : "long",
                "comment" : "timestamp"
              }, {
                "name" : "endDate",
                "type" : "long",
                "comment" : "timestamp"
              } ]
            } ],
            "default" : null,
          } ]
        } ],
        "default" : null,
      }, {
        "name" : "TimeConditions",
        "type" : [ "null", {
          "type" : "record",
          "name" : "TimeConditionsType",
          "fields" : [ {
            "name" : "TimeInterval",
            "type" : "TimeInterval",
          } ]
        } ],
        "default" : null,
      }, 
    },
  } ]
}
```

Should I add a

> "namespace":"my.types"

to the very beginning of the document and use it with avro like this

```
{
        "name" : "TimeConditions",
        "type" : [ "null", {
          "type" : "record",
          "name" : "TimeConditionsType",
          "fields" : [ {
            "name" : "TimeInterval",
            "type" : "my.types.TimeInterval",
          } ]
        } ],
        "default" : null,
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces help with code generation, primarily, such as Java package names. So, yes, you need to provide at least one dot-separation to not be in the "default package" where you will be unable to import a generated Java class.

To use other a pre-defined type in other fields, yes, you need the fully-qualified package and name, but when a namespace is defined, that's what will be used to reference other complex types, by default.

Also, `name` definitions should always follow Java class field naming conventions (not start with captial letter). More specifically, `private TimeInterval TimeInverval;` is not a valid definition.

Example - This AVDL definiton

```
@namespace("com.example")
protocol ExampleProtocol{
  record TimeInterval {
    timestamp_ms start;
    timestamp_ms end;
  }

  record Conditions {
    union {null, TimeInterval} timeInterval;
  }
}
```

Creates two AVSC files. Notice the nested record (of the same namespace) has no prefixed name

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Conditions",
  "namespace" : "com.example",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "timeInterval",
    "type" : [ "null", {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "TimeInterval",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "start",
        "type" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "logicalType" : "timestamp-millis"
        }
      }, {
        "name" : "end",
        "type" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "logicalType" : "timestamp-millis"
        }
      } ]
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "TimeInterval",
  "namespace" : "com.example",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "start",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "long",
      "logicalType" : "timestamp-millis"
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "end",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "long",
      "logicalType" : "timestamp-millis"
    }
  } ]
}
```

Then external JVM code could `import com.example.Conditions` for example

Comment: I do not quite understand. I'm just editing an existing avsc file. And I need to understand if I can use the namespace in one file? And how right?

Comment: As shown, namespace field is a top level property in an AVSC. What exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: I am not getting an error. Because I'm just editing the schema, trying to figure out the namespace and trying to figure out what exactly is wrong and how to use the namespace correctly.

Comment: So, something is wrong? But you're not getting any error? When you add the namespace and serialize new events, what happens?

Comment: I'm new to avro, and I'm just trying to figure out if my scheme is using namespace correctly and that's it

Comment: You only need namespace at the outer most level. "Top" isn't relevant since the keys aren't ordered in any specific way

Comment: I just need to understand how to inherit the same type through namespace multiple times in the same schema!!

Comment: What exactly is unclear from the example provided? The TimeInterval record is in the same namespace as Conditions, but namespace is only listed at the Conditions record. Like I said, try something. If you get an error, then edit your question to include it